# Sum of uncountable many pozitive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I am trying to solve this problem (which is by the way formulated in Probability Essentials by Jacod and Protter):

Let $(A_{\beta})_{\beta \in B}$ be a family of pairwise disjoint events. Show that if $P(A_{\beta}) > 0$ for each $\beta \in B$, then B must be countable.

I would like to generalize this question a little bit. It is widely known that a sum of infinitely many pozitive numbers can be finite. How can one prove that a sum of uncountable many positive numbers cannot be finite?

Thank you in advance for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$ \{\,\beta:P(A_\beta)>0\,\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \{\,\beta:P(A_\beta)>\tfrac1n\,\}.$$
So if the left is uncountable, at least one set on the right must be uncountable. But then already the sum over these contributes $>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1n=\infty$.