# Is there a name for the result that "a sum of uncountably many positive numbers cannot be finite"?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, terminology

There is a result that is fairly fundamental in measure theory, and is also quite nice in its own right, and so I think it would be nice for it to have a reasonably standard name.

> A set $S$ is uncountable if and only if for every $M>0$ and every function $f \colon S \to (0,\infty)$ there is a finite subset $C \subset S$ such that $\sum_{x \in C} f(x) > M$.

Does this result have a name?

[A roughly equivalent formulation can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/994999/222867.]

Comment: Luckily not everything has a name.

Comment: It looks like a true fact with no name. It also does not look like a very useful way to prove that a set is uncountable. Now you need to prove something for every function $f$, but the set of such functions is much larger than $S$.

Comment: @Gribouillis It’s a useful way to prove that a set is **not** uncountable (as implied by the title of my question); I only include the converse because it happens to be true and therefore makes the statement quite a nice equivalent formulation of uncountability.